# How to get the pop up(disclaimer Request for signature.. I consent to Electronic...) in embedded docusigning?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp, docusignapi

I have completed the embedded signing in docusign for my asp.net mvc site. Thanks to folks on SO and docusign documentation I was able to get it all working and was able to get the user signed pdf to download as well.

I just happen to see an embedded signing example at http://loancosample.azurewebsites.net/ and noticed that there is a pop up that shows up prompting the user to consent to use of Electronic signature. I just wish to know if there is any special setting that I need to do to get this in my embedded signing experience ,because currently I am not shown any pop up .. just a continue button and once I hit continue, my document is shown where I need to fill out and sign.

Any help is appreciated as always!
Thanks,
S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is in that example they are using the Classic Signing Experience, which gives a different look and feel of the disclosure page.

However, what I assume you are running into is your Consumer Disclosure Frequency set to "Once." If you are doing testing and using the same email address for a recipient then they will only need to accept the disclosure once and all following envelopes will allow you to simply "Continue." If you go to Preferences -> Features and change the Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure frequency to "Always" then you should have to accept it for every envelope.

Comment: I am testing this out in docusign demo account before we move to certify the Integration key for production, I went into demo account and found the Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure  tab, but under this could not find the place to change the frequency to "Always". Could you please point me to the right location? Thank you!

Comment: @sunnysideup if you don't see the ability to control the disclosure frequency you'll need to contact DocuSign to enable that ability for your account. If it is set to "Always" make sure you are using a unique ClientUserID for each call to ensure that recipient is being looked at as a unique recipient each time (who has not yet accepted the disclosure).

Comment: @RickeyS.. thanks! Yes I was getting the disclosure the very first time and  not later. I believe this works for our department for now! Thanks again!